# Access complete bound value of a textbox in attached property

Tags: c#, binding, textbox, attached-properties

With an attached property, I want to de-/increase the value of a textbox by that value when hitting Key.Up or Key.Down.

I defined the following property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SmallFloatIncrementProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "SmallFloatIncrement",
      typeof(double),
      typeof(InputService),
      new UIPropertyMetadata(0.1));

    public static double GetSmallFloatIncrement(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (double)d.GetValue(SmallFloatIncrementProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSmallFloatIncrement(DependencyObject d, double value)
    {
        d.SetValue(SmallFloatIncrementProperty, value);
    }
```

I have also registered for PreviewKeyDown on my TextBox and handle it like this:

```
    if(e.Key == Key.Up)
    {
      IncrementOrDecrementValue((DependencyObject)sender, true);
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
      IncrementOrDecrementValue((DependencyObject)sender, false);              
    }
```

...

```
    private static void IncrementOrDecrementValue(DependencyObject sender, bool doIncrement)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox)
        {
          TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
          var increment = GetSmallFloatIncrement((DependencyObject)sender);

          var text = tb.Text;
          double textBoxValue = 0.0;
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
          {
             try{
               textBoxValue = Convert.ToDouble(text, FormatProvider);
             }
             catch (FormatException)   { }
          }

          tb.Text = Convert.ToString((doIncrement) ? textBoxValue + increment : textBoxValue - increment, FormatProvider);
          ValidateResult(sender);        
        }
    }
```

I run into propblems when retrieving the value of the textbox. If for example the bound property is 1.234 but there is a StringFormat = N1 defined in the binding, the call tb.Text delivers 1.2 instead of the entire value. But I need to increment the original value by the specified amount (the value must be a multiple of the increment). Is there a way to retrieve the complete bound value of the textbox?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you don't want to change the textbox's value, you want to alter the view-model's value by the keys. Therefore the correct solution is to bind this behavior directly to the view-model.
So, here's the attached property holding the value itself.

```
public static double GetSmallFloatIncrement(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (double)obj.GetValue(SmallFloatIncrementProperty);
}

public static void SetSmallFloatIncrement(DependencyObject obj, double value)
{
    obj.SetValue(SmallFloatIncrementProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SmallFloatIncrementProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SmallFloatIncrement", typeof(double), typeof(TextBoxExtensions),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
```

Another attached property to implement this functionality and toggle it on/off:

```
public static bool GetSmallFloatIncrementOn(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (bool)obj.GetValue(SmallFloatIncrementOnProperty);
}

public static void SetSmallFloatIncrementOn(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
{
    obj.SetValue(SmallFloatIncrementOnProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SmallFloatIncrementOnProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SmallFloatIncrementOn", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxExtensions),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, OnSmallFloatIncrementOn));

static void OnSmallFloatIncrementOn(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)d;

    void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyArgs)
    {
        if (keyArgs.Key == Key.Up)
            IncrementOrDecrementValue(textBox, .01);
        else if (keyArgs.Key == Key.Down)
            IncrementOrDecrementValue(textBox, -.01);
    }

    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        textBox.PreviewKeyDown += OnKeyDown;
    else
        textBox.PreviewKeyDown -= OnKeyDown;
}
```

The function to increment gets simple now:

```
static void IncrementOrDecrementValue(TextBox textBox, double inc)
{
    var cur = GetSmallFloatIncrement(textBox);
    SetSmallFloatIncrement(textBox, cur + inc);
}
```

And now we can use it:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding VMValue, StringFormat=F1}" 
             local:TextBoxExtensions.SmallFloatIncrement="{Binding VMValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
             local:TextBoxExtensions.SmallFloatIncrementOn="True"/>
```

Note: with these increment and string format values you'll have to push the key 10 times until you see a value change in the TextBox. But this is something you can adjust to your taste.

Comment: Thanks armenm, this looks like a good solution. But I got one more question: I want to set the 'SmallFloatIncrement' in a style depending on a trigger value. How can I set the binding to VMValue there?

Comment: You can create an additional attached property for holding that value. You can use bindings with it then.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But what if in your example xaml code, you don't set the SmallFloatIncrement Binding in the TextBox directly, but use a Style (located somewhere in your resources), where you want to set the SmallFloatIncrementBinding depending on some trigger (e.g. Background is green)? You do not have direct access to the property VMValue, so is there another way to set the binding?